# Getting source of web page from open window in C#

Tags: c#, window, html

I want to get source of web page from any chrome, firefox, ie and etc. window with c#
What should i use?

My app:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
using System.Net;
//...
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient ())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

    // Or you can get the file content without saving it:
    string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://yoursite.com/page.html");
    //...
}
```

In htmlCode you will get html source as expected and display it on a text viewer.

Comment: client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");

But the url should be dynamic.How can i get url from open browser window?

Comment: You can send it through an ajax or a post call to server(assuming using Jquery or any other proper javascript library). You will find the current URL by window.location.href in javascript.